# How to perform efficient membership search on very large datasets in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, member, bioinformatics

My question regards list/set membership search efficiency. I want to compare a small set of genomic kmers (string of nucleotides) to a very large list of kmers to test for membership. The large list could be up to the ones of GB range, as this algorithm is designed for large eukaryotic genomes.

The smaller lists will only be in the KB range, but there could be potentially millions of those lists! Clearly, I am in dire need of an efficient way to search this large list.

According to similar questions I have seen, I shouldn't convert the large list to a set as it would cost too much memory. I have been using the smaller lists as sets, but it doesn't save me a noticeable amount of time.

Finally, once the script is done, it will be designed to run on large memory machines usually used for large genomic algorithms.

Thank You

Comment: This sounds like a job for a prefix trie - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Please provide examples of the data you're searching and approximation of the code you're using, as well as your expected output.

Comment: If you will have large memory machines available that can handle storing the large datasets in memory as a `set`, it might be the easiest method to just take advantage of the hardware.  How much memory in the large memory machines?

Comment: A `set` doesn't take as much more memory than a `list` as you think in CPython, but it sounds like in this case a more specialized container is in order.

Comment: If you're happy with the answer you should accepted it so the question is resolved...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BioPython](https://github.com/biopython/biopython) has a trie implementation for exactly this purpose.

```
from Bio import trie
tr = trie.trie()
```

Comment: Turns out a trie was a good way to go, and has dramatically increased my script's efficiency. Was initially confused by the trie concept, as I had no need for an associated key value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A [*trie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is likely a good data structure for the genomics, but you could also consider a *[BloomFilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)* (a probabilistic data structure that can provide amazingly space efficient set membership testing -- this is how some spell checkers store large dictionaries of valid words for example).